# Trying to print the right answer in Javascript using getElementById

Tags: javascript, printing, getelementbyid, perfect-numbers

I'm trying to find whether or a not a number is a perfect number, but I can't get it to print right. The numbers 6, 496, 8128 are perfect numbers but when I entered those it kept printing from `var res2` instead of `var res1`. What's the problem here, can anyone can help?

```js
function perfectNo(number) {
  var temp = 0;
  var res1 = "It is a perfect number";
  var res2 = "It is not a perfect number";
  for (var i = 1; i <= number / 2; i++) {
    if (number % i == 0) {
      temp += i;
    }
  }

  if (temp == number && temp != 0) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = res1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = res2;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="num">
<input type="button" onclick="perfectNo()" value="check">
<br>
<p>Answer:</p>
<p id="results"></p>
<br>
```

Comment: In your code, your function requires an argument, the number hasn't been sent

Comment: It is so obvious now... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with :

```
var number = document.getElementById("num").value;
```

Like this :

```js
function perfectNo() {
  var number = document.getElementById("num").value;
  console.log(number);
  var temp = 0;
  var res1 = "It is a perfect number";
  var res2 = "It is not a perfect number";
  for (var i = 1; i <= number / 2; i++) {
    if (number % i == 0) {
      temp += i;
    }
  }

  if (temp == number && temp != 0) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = res1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = res2;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="num">
<input type="button" onclick="perfectNo()" value="check">
<br>
<p>Answer:</p>
<p id="results"></p>
<br>
```